# Unsure as to why he can't says my files aren't finding the database

Tags: php, mysql

So I had my final and I did everything required and did well but my professor said that my files weren't finding the database. I really don't get why. My files when I'm using them work just fine in finding the database and adding and removing data. Why would it not be working for him?

Here is my sql file.

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS my_name_exam_db;

CREATE DATABASE my_name_exam_db;

DROP USER 'myfinal'@'localhost';

CREATE USER 'myfinal'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'bread';

GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON `my\_name\_exam\_db`.* TO 'myfinal'@'localhost';

CREATE table coordinate3d (
 number int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 x decimal (10,2) NOT NULL,
 y decimal (10,2) NOT NULL,
 z decimal (10,2) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (number)
);
```

Here's where I do a pdo to connect to the database.

```
<?php
    $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_name_exam_db';
    $username = 'myfinal';
    $password = 'bread';

    try {
        $db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $error_message = $e->getMessage();
        header ("Location: my_name_database_error.php");
        exit();
    }
?>
```

Here's one of my files that uses the database. I don't know if more is needed to find the issue. If so I'll provide more. It's kinda a lot of files.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!--Author: my name Coursecode: CSCI 4000 W1 Date: 12/11/18-->

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <title>my name secret calculator</title> 
</head>

<body>
<header>
<h1>my name Secret Calculator</h1>
</header>

<h2>The following coordinates are saved to the database table:</h2>
<br>
<?php
//delete_value($number)
include('my_name_database.php');
    global $db;
    $array = array();
    $formula_array = array();
$count = intval(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'count'));
for ($i=1; $i<=$count; $i++)
    {
        $x = intval(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'x'.$i));
        $y = intval(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'y'.$i));
        $z = intval(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'z'.$i));
        array_push($array, "x" .$i . "="  .number_format($x,2) . ", y" .$i . "="  .number_format($y,2) . ", z" .$i . "="  .number_format($z,2) .";" );
        array_push($formula_array, "f(x".$i.",y".$i.",z".$i.") = (x".$i.")<sup>3</sup> + (y".$i.")<sup>2</sup> + (z".$i.")<sup>2</sup> = " .number_format($x,2)."<sup>3</sup> + " .number_format($y,2)."<sup>2</sup> + " .number_format($z,2)."<sup>2</sup> = ".number_format(pow($x,3)+pow($y,2)+pow($z,2),2));
$query = 'INSERT INTO coordinate3d
                 (x, y, z)
                  VALUES
                 ( :x, :y, :z)';
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindValue(':x', $x);
    $statement->bindValue(':y', $y);
    $statement->bindValue(':z', $z);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->closeCursor();
    }
?>
<?php 

foreach($array as $v){

    echo $v;
    echo "<br>";
}
?>
<br>
<h3>The following function is applied to the coordinates:</h3>

<br>
<h3>f(xi,yi,zi) = (xi)<sup>3</sup> + (yi)<sup>2</sup> + (zi)<sup>2</sup></h3>
<br>
<?php 

foreach($formula_array as $v){

    echo $v;
    echo "<br>";
}
?>
<br>
<a href="index.php" >Return to home page</a>
<br>

<footer>&copy; 2015 my name kung fu school</footer>

</html>
```

Comment: Unless he told you what the error was, it's hard to help. If he loaded up your db on his system, perhaps he didn't change the user name/pass to suit his system. Maybe he didn't use the right host name. Maybe he doesn't have the PDO extension loaded. It really sounds like more of a configuration issue than an actual programming issue.

Comment: Without any error message, it is really hard to answer. What is the topology of the professor's set-up, what are the requirements, should there be additional documentation, are the environments the same, etc. "It works on my machine" does not guarantee anything...

Comment: Maybe you were supposed to load your database onto some server which your prof could access?

Comment: From the cli you can you reach and connect your database? You are using localhost, that means that http server and mysql server should be on the same server.

Comment: Yeh that's what I'm having trouble with cause I felt like I can't help if he doesn't tell me why. He uses phpMyAdmin and xampp. We use the same server. localhost.

Comment: @shadowsheep Ah, okay. How would I tell if they're on the same server. Sorry I'm a bit fuzzy with that.

Comment: It's very weird your professor can't debug this for you. Well, you know the old saying, those who can, do, those who can't, teach.

Comment: @shadowsheep Sorry I just noticed you were talking about using the cli. I seemed to be able to connect just fine.

Comment: @Mike lol yeah I'm actually annoyed because I can't help him fix his connection issue. I got 40 points off because he can't connect. All my code works, I connect fine using the same stuff he does.

Comment: Did you run the SQL file again on your local machine? I *think* the backslashes in the database name in your `GRANT` statement are unnecessary, so it's actually setting permissions for the wrong database name. It's also possible that, on a fresh install, the `DROP USER` statement is failing because that user doesn't exist, causing the rest of the SQL file to not be executed.

Comment: @Saiba If you can't figure out why he couldn't connect with MySQL, what about just using sqlite?

Comment: @rickdenhaan I took out the backslashes and removed the drop user statement. When I run it again I get an error for CREATE USER #1396 - Operation CREATE USER failed for 'kellyfinal'@'localhost'

Comment: @Mike I can try running it on sqlite that might help. I have to download it.

Comment: If you both use localhost, but both hosts are different, you're not using the same server... Are you sure you both use the same host, OS, server, database, etc? How did you hand over your files? Are you sure the permissions are correct?

Comment: @Kasper Agg Oh okay. In the instructions for the assignment he said we give the user privilidges of UPDATE, SELECT, DELETE, INSERT. If I provide screenshots of what his is supposed to look like and mine would that help?

Comment: That's a very limited answer to my questions (note: plural). I guess you can check the two versions yourself? What I meant with permissions was beyond the sql user, I was merely pointing to the variety of potential reasons why your assignment might fail on another server/machine/host/etc. File permissions could be another option...

Comment: @Kasper Agg. Yeah I'm sorry, I'm unsure how to answer fully. I believe we are using the same database because I give my database file to him and all my php and css files with it that link together. I'm unsure about the permissions and how to check that. I know we are supposed to be using localhost and xampp with Apache and mySql active.

Comment: Can you verify that the database and table are being created on the professor's machine?

Comment: I'm not positive. I'm assuming because he's using my file and he asked us to use DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS. So I create it then he uses my file to create again?

Comment: If you can't be sure how it is being executed and if it actually succeeds, there's no point in continuing this for me. I hope you'll find your answer (and please do share!).